# Как проверить, содержит ли массив те же элементы, что и в другом массиве

Tags: java

Допустим есть два массива: `int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3}` и `int[] a2 = {2, 3, 1}` и нужно проверить, содержаться ли все элементы массива `a1` в `a2` , не обращая внимания на последовательность чисел и вернуть false/true

Comment: При помощи цикла в цикле

Comment: не могли бы вы продемонстрировать?

Comment: Попробуйте сами, а если не будет получаться вот тогда приходите - поправим

Comment: Так проблема в том, что уже не получилось

Comment: @CoolBoy покажите код, в котором не получилось

Comment: public void containsAllChars(char [] ex){ boolean output = false;  for(char d:ex){ if(!this.contains(d) { output = false; }} return output; }

Comment: отсортируйте оба массива и проверьте. Для двух сортированных массивов такая проверка делается элементарно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант номер раз - сортировка массивов

```
public static boolean Contains(int[] source, int[] array){
    Arrays.sort(source);
    Arrays.sort(array);

    int i=0; int j=0;
    while (i<source.length && j<array.length){
        if (source[i] == array[j]){
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (source[i] > array[j]) j++;
        else return false;
    }
    return i == source.length;
}
```

Проверка

```
System.out.println(Contains(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{1, 2, 3}));
System.out.println(Contains(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
System.out.println(Contains(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 5}, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
```

Вывод

```
true
true
false
```

Вариант номер два - подсчет при помощи хеш таблицы

```
public static boolean Contains2(int[] source, int[] array){
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<source.length; i++)
    {
        int key = source[i];
        if (counts.containsKey(key))
            counts.put(key, counts.get(key) + 1);
        else counts.put(key, 1);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<array.length; j++){
        int key = array[j];
        if (counts.containsKey(key)){
            int val = counts.get(key);
            if (val > 0)
                counts.put(key, val-1);
        }
    }
    for(int v : counts.values()){
       if (v != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Проверка

```
System.out.println(Contains2(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{1, 2, 3}));
System.out.println(Contains2(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
System.out.println(Contains2(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 5}, new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
```

Вывод

```
true
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Написал на коленке, не проверял думаю самый короткий вариант. Поправьте если что то упустил.

```html
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4};
    int[] b = {1,2,3};
    boolean test=true;
    //массивы просто для примера чтоб их имена использовать
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      if(!(IntStream.of(b).anyMatch(x -> x == a[i])){
        test = false;
        System.out.println("Содержит не все элементы"); 
        break;}
    }
```

Comment: А что значит вот эта стрелочка '->' я её ни в одной книге и курсе не видел

Comment: Это лямбда выражение.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь буду знать

Comment: Это будет работать только в том случае, если повторения не должны учитываться (например [1, 1] в [1, 2, 3]). Также вы запускаете линейную операцию `anyMatch`, которая отработает как надо, но с точки зрения производительности гораздо выгодней использовать HashSet для таких операций.

Comment: @tym32167 вы имеете ввиду проверку количества одинаковых элементов и в том и в другом массиве?

Comment: Да, например, можно ли считать, что `[1]` содержит в себе `[1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: @tym32167 да это верно подмечено, только наличие будет проверять, а количество не проверит.